# How to place labels below buttons and consistently align the two horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I'm using margins on individual labels to align them centred and directly below buttons. This is hacky and inconsistent on different screen sizes.

```
<div id="langButtons">
   <input class="btn-group langButton" id="useJavascript" value="JavaScript" type="button"></input>
   <input class="btn-group langButton" id="useRuby" value="Ruby" type="button"></input>
   <input class="btn-group langButton" id="usePython" value="Python" type="button"></input>
   <input class="btn-group langButton" id="useHTML" value="HTML" type="button"></input>
   <input class="btn-group langButton" id="useCSS" value="CSS" type="button"></input>
   <input class="btn-group langButton" id="useSwift" value="Swift" type="button"></input>
</div>

<div id="langDescriptions">
  <label style="margin-left: 4.8%" class="langDescription" id="JavaScript">Javascript</label>
  <label style="margin-left: 6.8%" class="langDescription" id="Ruby">Ruby</label>
  <label style="margin-left: 4.5%" class="langDescription" id="Python">Python</label>
  <label style="margin-left: 5.4%" class="langDescription" id="HTML">HTML</label>
  <label style="margin-left: 5.3%" class="langDescription" id="CSS">CSS</label>
  <label style="margin-left: 4.8%" class="langDescription" id="Swift">Swift</label>
</div>
```

There must be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put them in a parent element with `text-align: center` also `input` tags are self closing -- you don't need `</input>`

Here is an example of what I mean: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ajc8pqh9/

```css
.grouping{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.langDescription{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="langButtons">
<div class="grouping">
   <input class="btn-group langButton" id="useJavascript" value="JavaScript" type="button">
   <label for="useJavascript" class="langDescription" id="JavaScript">Javascript</label>
</div>
<div class="grouping">
   <input class="btn-group langButton" id="useRuby" value="Ruby" type="button">
     <label class="langDescription" id="Ruby">Ruby</label>
</div>
<div class="grouping">
   <input class="btn-group langButton" id="usePython" value="Python" type="button">
  <label class="langDescription" id="Python">Python</label>
</div>
<div class="grouping">
   <input class="btn-group langButton" id="useHTML" value="HTML" type="button">
  <label class="langDescription" id="HTML">HTML</label>
</div>
<div class="grouping">
   <input class="btn-group langButton" id="useCSS" value="CSS" type="button">
  <label class="langDescription" id="CSS">CSS</label>
</div>
<div class="grouping">
   <input class="btn-group langButton" id="useSwift" value="Swift" type="button">
  <label class="langDescription" id="Swift">Swift</label>
</div>
</div>
```